# Defining Rules for My Library in android

Tags: android, android-library

I'm relatively new to this library making the segment.

I've a library and that has some limitation like Min API level of my library is 17.

And When someone tries to use my library with his App min API level lesser than mine. Then I just want to warn him somehow to make him aware.

I've read me but that's not of big use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your library requires minSdk = 17 it won't compile into projects having minSdk lower than 17. The build will fail with an error saying it's not possible. You don't need to provide any 'warnings' yourself.